# When using facebook api getting "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

When using Facebook API getting The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

---

Here is my code:

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PageAccessToken"];

```
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Hi Sir Patrick, i use  (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() , but it seems the problem is on my Token with Facebook during request because i tried other token for my other FB page and it works. Only my problem is on my official FB page getting the error and also it was working before. Thanks!